# Concatenar ficheros sin respetar nombre de columna

Tags: pandas, concat

Quiero concatenar ficheros que tienen las mismas columnas, y el mismo tipo de dato por columna pero que a veces tienen titulo de columna diferentes. No quiero que me cree un columna nueva por cada titulo, sino que respete el orden de la columna simplemente:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}, index = [1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[5,6], 'c':[5,4]}, index = [1,2])
print(df1)
print(df2)

   a  b
1  1  3
2  2  4

   b  c
1  5  5
2  6  4
```

Lo que espero

```
   x  y
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  5  5
4  6  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo más sencillo puede ser extraer los valores de los dataframes (usando su propiedad `.values`) pues éstos no contienen ya nombres de columnas ni índices, sólo los datos, para usar `numpy.concatenate()` para unirlos en una sola matriz y usar ésta para crear el dataframe resultado que buscas. Una vez creado ese resultado ya le puedes asignar los nombres de columnas que quieras.

Es decir:

```
import numpy as np

r = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1.values, df2.values]),  columns=["x", "y"])
print(r)
```

```
   x  y
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  5  5
3  6  4
```

Y si, por lo que sea, quieres que el índice comience en 1:

```
r.index += 1
print(r)
```

```
   x  y
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  5  5
4  6  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrió una forma que funciona, simplemente resetee los nombres de columna de cada fichero, después los concatene, y para terminar puse los nombres de columna a la tabla final.